# Getting permission denied while using virtual env

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to install Open CV 2 on a shared hosting inside a virtualenv.

I already got numpy and all those stuff downloaded using Pip. I'm just having a bit of trouble with OpenCV2

I run this command in the ssh session

```
(penv)[dire]$ cmake -D MAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$VIRTUAL_ENV/local/ -D PYTHON_EXECTUABLE=$PYTHONPATH/python2.7 -D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

and the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bashtroubles/website.com/public/NNPics/penv/bin/cmake", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cmake())
  File "/home/bashtroubles/website.com/public/NNPics/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmake/__init__.py", line 33, in cmake
    raise SystemExit(_program('cmake', sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/home/bashtroubles/website.com/public/NNPics/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmake/__init__.py", line 29, in _program
    return subprocess.call([os.path.join(CMAKE_BIN_DIR, name)] + args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
(penv)[dire]$
```

This is also my .bashrc if it matters

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# Load pythonbrew
alias pb='pythonbrew'
export PYTHONPATH=~/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib
[[ -s /home/bashtroubles/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]] && source /home/bashtroubles/.python$

# Load custom python installation
export PATH=~/opt/python-2.7.3/bin:${PATH}
export PYTHONPATH=~/opt/python-2.7.3/lib
```

The specific version is opencv-2.4.13 and the python version is 2.7.3

I believe the issue is because it's using the python2.7 from

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

Any ideas on how to get this going without a permission denied issue?

Comment: Did you try `sudo cmake ...`?

Comment: @damores: Presumably the whole point of defining the install prefix to be a virtualenv is to avoid the need for `sudo`; it's being installed to a user owned virtualenv, not the system global directories.

Comment: @damores It's inside a shared hosting where I do not have sudo. And yeah ShadowRanger is right. That is the whole point

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem. It looks like the binary it's trying to call isn't marked as an executable. I ran this to change the permissions

```
sudo chmod +x -R /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmake-3.13.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/bin
```